How to find Electric Field using Gauss's Law for a uniformly charged sphere
The ball, $B_r(0)$ has a uniform charge distribution of and radius, R. We'll define our charge density as $$\rho= \rho_0\Theta(R-|\textbf{r}|)$$
We want to find the electric field inside and outside of the ball using Gauss's Law.
Starting with Maxwell's equations:
$$\tag{1}\nabla \cdot E(\textbf{r}) = -\rho(\textbf{r})/\epsilon_0$$
and because of Maxwell's equation for the curl is 0, it is assumed that the electric field is completely normal to the ball i.e. it only points in the $\hat{\textbf{r}}$ direction. Because of this, we can write
$$E(\textbf{r}) = E(r)\hat{\textbf{r}} = E(r)\textbf{r}/r, |\textbf{r}| = r$$
Now I just need to apply Gauss's Theorem to (1) to obtain the electric field:
$$\tag{2}\oint  E(r)\hat{\textbf{r}}\cdot d\textbf{S} = -\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}\int_0^{R}r^2\Theta(R-r)\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta d \phi dr$$
For the right hand integral I get:
$$\tag{3}-\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_0^{R}r^2\rho_0\Theta(R-r)\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta d \phi dr =
\\ -\frac{4\pi \rho_0}{\epsilon_0}\int_0^{R}r^2 dr 
\\ = -\frac{4\pi R^3\rho_0}{3\epsilon_0}$$
Giving:
$$\tag{4}\oint  E(r)\hat{\textbf{r}}\cdot \hat{\textbf{r}}dS = -\frac{4\pi R^3\rho_0}{3\epsilon_0}$$
Now we integrate our path integral on the left which should be exceptionally easy, because $E$ is not a function of either integration variables, so we should get:
$$\tag{5}\oint  E(r)\hat{\textbf{r}}\cdot \textbf{dS} \\
R^2 E(r) \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta d\phi \\
= 4\pi R^2E(r)$$
Re-arranging, I have for my Electric field:
$$\tag{6}E(r) = \frac{\rho_0 }{3\epsilon_0}R$$
Something is clearly missing in my procedure as we can see from equation (11) here, our electric field should end up being:
$$\tag{7}E(r) = \frac{\rho_0}{3\epsilon_0}\bigg[r\Theta(R-r)+\frac{R^3}{r^2}\Theta(r-R)\bigg]$$
Maybe I integrated the heaviside step function wrong?

In Equation (2) your integral should be to the observation location $r$ and not to the radius of the ball $R$, and this observation location can be either inside or outside the ball. Or else the Heaviside step function won't get to do anything. Your ball must also be non-conducting in order to have constant charge distribution inside a volume. You might also want to prove that spherical symmetry leads to purely radial fields. You also did not copy Equation (11) correctly.

So the setup of my integral was wrong, then. So, modifying equation (2) $$-\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}\Bigg(\int_0^r r^2 \Theta(R-r)dr + \int_r^R r^2\Theta(R-r)dr\Bigg)\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$and now we're integrating over a domain of integration where the charge density is non-zero which goes fromt he origin, to the point of observation, $r$, and then from $r$ to $R$.

@naturallyInconsistent Probably a silly question, but just to verify if I have this right, suppose the charge density were nonzero outside the sphere and 0 inside the sphere, would we then integrate from the surface of the sphere to an observation point $r>R$ and then to $R_o$ for where the nonzero charge density ends outside the sphere?

No. In the case of spherical symmetry, you always integrate from the centre of symmetry to observation point, no more, no less.
